# Rancher getting 404 responses form private registry URL's

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry, rancher

I have rancher set up. I have a private registry using a self signed certificate setup. I followed the guide at  http://docs.rancher.com/rancher/configuration/registries/ to set up registry with in rancher. I have also created an ami with my self signed certificate installed. I'm using this ami to create my new hosts. I have a working docker compose file. I have built and pushed my image out to my private registry. When I run rancher compose rancher is unable to get the image from my private registry. Instead rancher is hitting a URL on the registry that is sending back a 404. Why is rancher hitting the wrong URL?

Comment: have you gone through all of this http://docs.rancher.com/rancher/configuration/registries/ ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have updated my question with more detail.